# Collecting performance and runtime metrics in cpp

Tags: c++, go, influxdb, metric

I am aware that go language has an excellent support for collecting metric data. We can visualize the data in any manner we want using handy tools like [go-metrics](https://golanglibs.com/top?q=go-metrics) and [influxDB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.12/introduction/getting_started/).

I have a CPP application (similar to bitcoin) and looking for an easy way to collect some metrics. Can any CPP developer recommend anything you are aware of?

Comment: This question is likely to be closed here as off-topic, try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. As for the real answer, you can try tools like oprofile, valgrind, perf and similar, depending on your needs.

Comment: you've asked a long time ago, but I've recently started a c++ client for InfluxDB: [influxdb-cpp-rest](https://github.com/d-led/influxdb-cpp-rest).